# Nothing is being output to the console! (Java, Eclipse Mars)

Tags: java, eclipse, console, eclipse-mars

So basically I am experimenting with writing a path finding program that find a path from some point in a 10*10 grid to another, that is fine.

I have a class `Path` that is an ArrayList of `GridSquare`s (which are just glorified co-ordinates).

I have written a small method within the `Path` class to display the path, and this is where the problem, which is so minor but so very infuriating, arises.

When I try to run the code, and call `displayPath`, ***nothing*** is output to the console and the program terminates with no errors.

Here is the code for `displayPath`:

```
public void displayPath(){
    System.out.println("This is displayPrint"); //This line is included to make sure the program calls the method correctly.
    for(int i=1; i==10; i++){
        for(int j=1; j==10; j++){
            if(this.includesSquare(i, j)){
                System.out.print("[x]");
            } else {
                System.out.print("[ ]");
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

I included the first line to ensure that the console/System.out.print() was working correctly and this gets displayed every time the method is called.

Here is the code for `includesSquare`:

```
public boolean includesSquare(int x, int y){
    for(GridSquare square : this.path){
        if(square.getX()==x && square.getY()==y){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have uninstalled and re-installed Eclipse, copied the java files into a new project ect and nothing seems to make any difference. I know the console is working fine as it displays the first line of `displayPath` correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this: `\\This line is included [...]` part of your code? Because you comment with forward slashes, not backslashes.

Comment: no added that in as part of the question! my mistake!

Comment: What is your intent with `for(int i=1; i==10; i++)` ? Specifically the `i == 10` condition

Comment: basically I want the loop to finish when i or j==10, is this not possible with a for loop, I was not aware!

Comment: change the condition to `j<=10`.With your code you are saying that execute the loop only if `j=10` and nothing else

Comment: You can, but instead that condition is moreso used to express when you want the loop to keep running. When you initialize `i` to 1, it won't be `==` to 10, and so the loop doesn't run even once :). Instead you want `i < 10` so that your loop runs as long as `i` is less than 10. And as you say, it will terminate when i == 10.

Comment: Wow you uninstalled and re-installed? Come on the site and let us look it over before going as extreme as uninstalling/installing.  :)  We are here to help.

Comment: it is an easy fix, can be replaces with i<11 but i didn't see the issue with using == as they both resolve to a Boolean anyway.
Ahhh @Trobbins that makes sense!

Comment: yeah! @gonzo i read elsewhere that people with a similar problem had managed to solve by reinstalling! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for(int i=1; i==10; i++)` and `for(int j=1; j==10; j++)` will not work.

The middle condition (`i==10`) is supposed to say when the loop is supposed to be executed. As it is, you are saying you only want the loop to execute when `i` is equal to 10. Since `i` is initially equal to 1, it will skip right over the loop.

What you will likely want is

```
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
```

This way, when `i` is equal to 1, it satisfies the condition that it is less than 10, so the loop will get executed and `i` will increment. This will keep happening until `i` is equal to 10, at which point the condition `i<10` fails, so the loop will exit.

In less words, you want your condition to say "loop *while* this is true" as opposed to "loop *until* this is true".

Comment: Was gonna edit that in after. Patience @MarounMaroun! :P

Comment: @gla3dr you're allowed to wait until your answer is complete before posting your answer.

Comment: They won't work because if `i=1`, then `i==10` is false, and the loop will terminate. Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @gla3dr Thanks! for some reason i was thinking about the middle statement as a sort of 'go until this' statement which doesn't actually make a whole lot of sense, but id just never thought about it before!

Comment: @Trobbins When you say I am allowed to, do you mean I should?

Answer (score 1):

`for(int i=1; i==10; i++){` is where your problem lies.

The syntax for the for loop is as follows:

for(`<initial condition>`; `<checking condition>`; `<incrementing>`)

So what you have is

Staring from `i = 1`, increment by 1 while `i == 10`. Well since `i` starts at 1, you've already failed at the first step!

Turn your for loop into while loop to understand this better:

```
int i = 1;
while(i == 10) {
    doSomething();
    i++;
}
```

So of course that won't work.